# Where should I place data base file to run example project?

Tags: php

I'm new in PHP programming.  I have found a project on [github](https://github.com/puttyvikas/shopping).

This is screen shot of the project containing the file  [githum PHP project files](https://github.com/puttyvikas/shopping)

I extracted project and placed in my `wamp www` folder and access via http://localhost /shopping-master/index.php

It gives a connection error.

Please help me.  How do I connect to the database?

Where should I place sample code database to run project easily?

```
this is screen shot 

enter code here


//connect.php file
   <?php
$server_name = "localhost";
$user_name = "root";
$pass = "";
//$db = "easygaadi";
$db = "shopping";
$conn_error = "not connected";

if(@!mysql_connect($server_name,$user_name,$pass) || @!mysql_select_db($db))
{
die($conn_error);
} //else { 
//echo "<span style='background-color:yellow'>Connected to Database    
Successfully!!</span><br>";
//}




 //this is index.php file



     <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <?php require 'connect.php'; 
    ob_start();
 session_start();
 ?>
 <head>
```

Comment: this is screen shot  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/koLTq.jpg
    [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/a7ZTP.png

Comment: just tell me in connect.php file  its use $db = "shopping";   & when i extract project thiere is a file   shopping.sql     tell me what do i do? place this file in somewhere in www folder  or create new database nsmed"shopping" from phpMyAdmin  ???

Answer (score 1):

You have to import that `.sql` file to phpmyadmin. You need to build an database for that script with table, views, triggers etc. If you don't do this, the script will try to connect some tables, but it's going to be unsuccessfull. First of all, you need to create and mysql user and database, then you should import that shopping `.sql` file from phpmyadmin to there. After that, you need to configure `connect.php`(mysql username, password and database name fields must be matched with yours.) file as you created informations on the first stage.

Comment: give me any example tutorial is possible ??  i serch google no tutorial i find which help how to run sample project

Comment: Think that you are not connecting your database and your code. This is all about that. That sql file contains the database of all that application, so you need to create your own database and import that file via phpmyadmin. after that you should set those user_name, pass, database parameters according to your own configurations. You don't have to need a tutorial for that one if you need an help about it, you can find a million kind of tutorial on the google which is similar with that project.